# How to complete this query function?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

#### Table A ###(Code, Value are combined primary key)

```
Code    Value

1     |   b

1     |   c

3     |   c
```

#### Table B

```
Value

b
```

#### Table C

```
Value

c
```

I would like to write a query of 'Code' from Table A.

The condition is that 'Code' should contain Value 'c'.

If 'Code' contains Value'b', this Code shouldn't be queried. (that's, Code 1 has value b and value c, so Code 1 needs to be excluded)

But I'm not available to do that query.

The expected outcome might be '3'

I want to use intersect but MySql doesn't contain this function yet.
So I tried some codes.
I'm sure that my codes have problems but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM A B C
WHERE A.Value IN
    (SELECT Value FROM B)
AND A.Value NOT IN
    (SELECT Value FROM C);
```

Could you give me some tips on my questions?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are joining a, b and c. you almost got it.

```
select distinct a.value
from a
where a.value in (select value from b)
and a.value not in (select value from c)
```

or you can use `join`

```
select * 
from a 
inner join b where b.value = a.value
    and not in (select value from c)
```